# How to transfer a javascript two dimensional array to a controller in asp mvc with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a webpage where the user creates his matrices, insert doubles into each cells, enter an equation and press a button "calculate" to get the result.
The problem occurs when I'm trying to send the matrices to the controller using ajax.

### Dictionary Type

```
Dictionary<char, double[,]> matrices
```

### Javascript Dictionary

Initialization of the dictionary :

```
var matricesDictionary = {};
```

Initialization of the 2 dimensional array :

```
 var matrixContent = new Array(matrix.width);
    for (var c = 0; c < matrix.width; c++)
        matrixContent[c] = new Array(matrix.height);
```

Filling of the 2 dimensional array :

```
$('#' + matrix.name + " input").each(function () {
        var values = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        var line = values[0];
        var column = values[1];
        matrixContent[line][column] = parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
```

Add of a new element to the dictionary :

```
matricesDictionary[matrix.name] = matrixContent;
```

Content of a matrix "a" of 12x12

[Matrices Dictionary Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8yMA.png)

### Ajax Request

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Matrix/Matrix',
        type: "POST",
        data: { matrices: matricesDictionary, exp: exp },
    });
```

### Controller parameters

```
public IActionResult Matrix(Dictionary<char, double[,]> matrices, string exp)
```

The request is received by the controller, the "exp" variable has the correct values and the dictionary has the keys but their content is null.

[Exception NullReferenceException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIdrc.png)

Comment: you are only passing key in 2D array not value  matricesDictionary[matrix.name,matrixContent];